# Docker cloud hosting with persistent storage

Tags: docker, cloud, persistent-volumes

I need to find a cloud provider to host a simple docker service but with a persistent storage attached.

I know I can achieve this using GCE (VM + docker + volume mounted from VM) but this looks a bit too complicated (not complex though), and I was wondering if someone here knew a cloud provider providing this kind of solution, in a very simple way.

Thanks

Comment: Would AWS Fargate with EFS be a candidate? I think it would be too slow for using like a VM, but not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Been using GCE vm hosting a docker instance ... Easy enough for now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any cloud providers which do this as you describe. I'd wager that it's due to the simplicity of a user setting it up on their own, compared to the headache of them taking that task on themselves and lack of demand for non-kubernetes docker management.

Docker setup is super simple and broadly documented, so I'd still recommend a VM of your choice from a reputable host. Once logged into the VM, you can have docker up and running in less than 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was suspecting this.